# Unable to start the mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

when i submit the map-reduce job i am getting the following info and the mapreduce job is not initiating.

```
INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use 
fs.defaultFS
```

How to fix this one,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, using fs.default.name instead of fs.defaultFS is not Root cause of MapReduce Job startup.

You may check whether the Name node is in Safemode or Not.

fs.default.name is core-site.xml configuration, you can change it to using fs.defaultFS.

Please also provide logs/output of `hadoop jar` command.

OR You may also check whether the Hadoop examples are running properly or not for troubleshooting.